# Model Predictive Power and better prediction of 1 or 0 in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I have two questions about the Logistic Regression model in scikit-learn:

1. Which statistic can show me model predictive power?
2. Which statistic can show me whether my model better predicts event 1 or event 0?

Comment: `results = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)`

Answer (score 1):

> Which statistic can show me model predictive power?

It totally depends on the specific problem you're trying to solve.   For example, either you have imbalanced classes or if making false negative mistakes will cost you more than false positives (not identifying the patient malignant tumor). Therefore, `accuracy`, `precision` aka positive predictive value, 'recall`aka sensitivity or true positive rate, and etc could either show your model's true power in predicting the classes. Furthermore, in`scikit-learn`you can explicitly specify which scoring you're looking for. As an example for`accuracy`:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# Generate features matrix and target vector
X, y = make_classification(n_samples = 10000,
                               n_features = 3,
                               n_informative = 3,
                               n_redundant = 0,
                               n_classes = 2,
                               random_state = 1)
# Create logistic regression
logit = LogisticRegression()
# Cross-validate model using accuracy
cross_val_score(logit, X, y, scoring="accuracy")

array([ 0.95170966,  0.9580084 ,  0.95558223])
```

[More](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter) on `scoring` parameter from scikit-learn documentation.

> Which statistic can show me whether my model better predict event 1 or event 0 ?

The Receiving Operating Characteristic (ROC) curve is a common method for evaluating the quality of a binary classifier. ROC compares the presence of true positives and false positives at every probability threshold. By plotting the ROC curve, we can see how the model performs. In `scikit-learn`, we can use `roc_curve` to calculate the true and false positives at each threshold, then plot them.

Moreover, you can use `predict_proba` in logistic regression to see the *soft* classification. You can access them after fitting the model and they represent predicted probabilities for each observation. Following the example above:

```py
features_train, features_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
# Create another classifier
logit = LogisticRegression() 
logit.fit(features_train, target_train) 
# Get predicted probabilities
target_probabilities = logit.predict_proba(features_test)[:,1]
# Create true and false positive rates
false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, threshold = roc_curve(target_test, target_probabilities)

# Plot ROC curve
plt.title("Receiver Operating Characteristic")
plt.plot(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
plt.plot([0, 1], ls="--")
plt.ylabel("True Positive Rate")
plt.xlabel("False Positive Rate")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Which statistic can show me model predictive power ? For example CV-f1 score
2. Which statistic can show me whether my model better predict event 1 or event 0 ? [True negative and true positive rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)